# name clashing in nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I am new to NuGet and wonder - how does Visual Studio resolves the situation where two or more installed NuGet packages provide commands which have the same name.

How does that ambiguity get resolved or does it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are resolved using the underlying version of PowerShell's rules. Visual Studio has nothing to do with it. Generally speaking, the last loaded command wins. You can learn about these rules by running:

`get-help about_command_precedence`

or by reading about the topic online:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx